# Minimum and maximum exposure to virus

Tags: virology, coronavirus, infection, infectious-diseases

Is it possible to say that there is a maximum exposure time for the virus so that even an exposure time beyond that - will leave us with the same chances of infection?

If so, is there a way to estimate the interval between the minimum exposure time for infection and the maximum exposure time for infection and what happens inside?

Answer (score 1):

No, on cannot say it this way, since further expose always carries a risk of getting infected.

However, one could argue that after certain time of exposure one is nearly certainly infected, so being exposed longer doesn't really change the result. This statement could be formulated more rigorously in terms of [compartamental epidemiological models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology). If we take the figure for the SIR model in the linked article, we see that the number of the susceptible individuals (S) quickly drops about time 0.2-0.4, after which it is almost zero, i.e., there are almost no uninfected individuals in the population.
[image]

The numbers of susceptible (S), infected (I), and recovered (R) individuals can be normalized by the total number of the individuals in the population ($N=S+I+R$), and then interpreted as the probabilities of a person being uninfected ($p_S=S/N$), infected ($p_I=I/N$) or recovered ($p_R=R/N$). These probabilities will behave in time in teh same way as shon in the figure (but with different y scale), i.e., the probability of being ininfected would first be nearly constant, and then quickly decrease to nearly zero.